# How to handle overtime crons

Tags: cron

Suppose if i have cron tasks running every minute. And if each time, that task takes more than one minute to run, what will happen. Will the next cron wait for the first cron or will it run without any checks.

I want to run a cron task every minute and I don't over lapping cron tasks like that in case of a long running task/situation.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you run. If it's your own script, you can implement a locking/lock checking mechanism to avoid running duplicates.

But that's not `cron`'s job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cron will go ahead and start your 1+ minute-running process every minute until something crashes.

You'll want to put a lock of some sort into your job if you can to basically do this at start-up:

```
if not get_lock()
    print "Another process is running"
    exit
```

This, of course, assumes that you own the code running.  If you're running a command that you didn't code, then I'd recommend building a shell wrapper that implements the above pseudocoded logic where get_lock() will see if another process like this one is running.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, CRON will run your script every minute regardless of whether another instance of your script is still running.

If you want to avoid this and don't fancy implementing your own locking mechanism then you could try using a CRON alternative called The Fat Controller which is a daemon that will continually re-run scripts.   You can optionally specify an interval between runs and also optionally specify a maximum execution time so if a script goes AWOL then it can be killed.

There's some use cases and more information on the website:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/